# Most efficient way to search for a value and return its index in a vector?

Tags: c++, vector, indexing

I am trying to iterate through a vector (k), and check if it contains a value (key), if it does, I want to add the value found at the same index of a different vector (val) and then add whatever value is found there to a third vector (temp).

```
for(int i = 0; i < k.size(); ++i)
{
  if(k.at(i) == key)
   {
     temp.push_back(val.at(i));
   } 
}
```

I've learned a lot lately but I'm still not super advanced in C++, this code does work for my purposes but it is extremely slow. It can handle small vectors of sizes like 10 or 100, but takes much too long for sizes bigger like 1000, 10000 or even 1000000.

My question is, is there a faster and more efficient way to do this?

I've tried this:

```
std::vector<int>::iterator it = k.begin(); 
while ((iter = std::find(it, k.end(), key)) != k.end()) 
{ 
 int index = std::distance(k.begin(), it); 
 temp.push_back(val.at(index));
}
```

I thought maybe using a vector iterator would speed things up, but I can't get the code to work due to bad_alloc errors that I'm not sure how to fix.

Does anyone know what I can do to make this little bit of code *much* faster?

Comment: Do you need to keep the data in two separate vectors? It seems like a perfect job for a map or unordered map.

Comment: @krzaq No I suppose I don't, the k and val vectors are equal to each other in a way at their indexes, and they're also the same size. Is there a way I could put them together? And would that speed it up?

Comment: You're spending time in lookup and copying the data. Maps can help a lot with lookup times.

Comment: Either a `std::unordered_multimap<K,V>` or a `std::unordered_map<K, std::vector<V>>` would seem appropriate for this task, where `K` is the hashable key type, and `V` is the value type respectively. I included the latter because you seem to want them all, and rather than creating a value vector via copy over an equal range, a direct mapped-to vector may be more performant, especially if you can just use a reference to the vector contained in the map and avoid copying *entirely*.

Answer (score 6):

Here are a few things you could do:

1. Pre-allocate the data for `temp`, so that `push_back` doesn't cause repeated allocations:

   ```
   temp.reserve(k.size());
   ```
2. If `k` is sorted, you can use that fact to speed things up a bit:

   ```
   auto lowerIt = std::lower_bound(k.begin(), k.end(), key);
   auto upperIt = std::upper_bound(k.begin(), k.end(), key);

   for (auto it = lowerIt; it != upperIt; ++it)
       temp.push_back(val[it - k.begin()]);
   ```
3. `at` does bounds checking, so it is a tad bit slower than `[]`. You obviously have to guarantee that you are never accessing an out of bounds index.

Comment: Very helpful, I've sorted it and sped it up a ton, I kept [ ]  because I won't ever be accessing an out of bounds index, and I've pre-allocated temp.

Comment: I didn't mean to submit that comment yet but I don't know how to edit them once posted. I did all 3 things as I've said, and it sped it up a lot but not enough to handle 10k or 100k. I've noticed that if I run vectors with 1000 elements it goes from 0 - 1000 at the blink of an eye, but if I do 10,000 elements, it takes 5 times as long to get from 0 to 1000, do you know why this could be?

Comment: @Dante I would say that a 1000 element vector can be stored in L cache, instead of RAM, which is faster than RAM. But with 10,000 elements, it cannot be stored in cache, and so is is slower

Answer (score 2):

Besides Rakete's suggestions:

If your keys vector is sorted - use [`std::binary_search`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/binary_search) instead of `std::find` and then just iterate until the next value/end of vector.

If you're free to change your data structures, keep your data in [`std::unordered_multimap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_multimap) and use [`equal_range`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_multimap/equal_range) to access elements with your desired keys.